# Попытка завершения сессии

Tags: php

Есть класс для формы входа:

```
 class Controller_login extends Controller
{

    function action_index()
    {

            session_start(); // Старт сесси
            $error["login_status"]=''; // объявление переменной с ошибкой
            if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
                if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
                    $error["login_status"] = "access_fail1";
                }
                else
                {
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $password=$_POST['password'];
                    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql","mysql");// конект
                    $email = stripslashes($email);// защита от иньекций
                    $password = stripslashes($password);
                    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
                    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
                    $db = mysql_select_db("myshop", $connection);// выбор БД
                    $query = mysql_query("select * from tblUsers where Password='$password' AND Email='$email'", $connection);// SQL запрос
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($rows == 1) {
                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$email; // инициализация сессии
                        header("location: /profile"); // редирект
                    } else {
                        $error["login_status"] = "access_fail2";
                        header("location: /login");
                    }
                    mysql_close($connection); // закрываем соединение
                }
        }

        $this->view->generate('login_view.php', 'template_view.php');
    }

}
```

Далее к форме profile я подключаю session.php в котором вывожу email записанный в сессии:

```
<?php session_start();
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql","mysql");
$db = mysql_select_db("myshop", $connection);
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select Email from tblUsers where Email='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['Email'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
    mysql_close($connection);
}
```

Так вот, задача завершить все эти сессии по клику кнопки выхода, но выскакивает ошибка

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in F:\Openserver\OpenServer\domains\gidrolux.ru\application\controllers\controller_main.php on line 18

Выход пытаюсь осуществить так:

```
function action_logout()
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы можно было работать с сессией, надо её начать.

```
function action_logout()
{
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

**upd**. пара ссылок на документацию

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) создаёт или восстанавливает сессию (на основе `session id`, переданного через `GET`-параметр или `cookie`).

Чтобы задать имя сессии, надо вызвать [`session_name($name)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-name.php) до `session_start()`

Comment: Что то ерунда какая то))) Проблема не в этом. А в том что у него нет сессии на момент уничтожения. А просто создать новую и моментально её уничтожить это не решение его вопроса.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, `session_start` не создает новую сессию, он просто создает ее и если до этого (в прошлые обращения к сайту) в нее что-то писали, то в этой "новой" сессии (которая старая) все и будет.

Comment: Спасибо! Только знакомлюсь с сессиями в php) Василий, вы не правы, все сессии уничтожаются как и задумано, только теперь вопрос **как завершить конкретную сессию**, а не все?

Comment: @Денис присвоить ей имя? `session_start('NAME')`, `session_destroy('NAME')`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а так разве можно? не надо советовать того, чего не до конца понимаете

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев через session_name()? как мне потом обратиться к ней? ведь в session_destroy() я не могу параметр передать, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Денис, что значит "конкретную сессию"? Уничтожается только одна сессия - того пользователя, который это действие вызывает, а не всех пользователей.

Comment: @ВОРОН пользователь разве не может создать несколько сессий? банально вход в аккаунт и корзина покупок? session_destroy() уничтожит все эти сессии.

Comment: @Денис Сессия это массив, ты можешь сделать поля какие нужны тебе `$_SESSION['auth']`, `$_SESSION['someElse']`, при этом `auth` может быть сама объектом/массивом

Comment: @Денис, это будет одна сессия. `session_start` не создает новую сессию, он просто ее создает. Если вам надо оставить определенные данные - удаляйте лишнее и оставляйте только необходимое. Думайте о сессии как о массиве `$_SESSION`, если грубо, то `session_start()` после `session_destroy()` создает новый массив (т.е. идет создание чистой сессии), а если `session_destroy()` не вызывался, то `session_start()` просто используется старый массив. Соответственно, если надо удалить что-либо определенное - это определенное и можно удалить. Либо удалить сессию и опять записать туда данные

Comment: спасибо, разобрался)